# Inline JavaScript to open the url

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a button link to a website.
When the button is clicked, it opens the website.

The following is the inline JS method, but somehow it does not work.

```
<p><input type="submit" onclick="window.location.href('http://www.google.com')" value="Google" /></p>
```

Comment: you are missing your **following inline js***. shouldnt it be closed for **unclear what you are asking**?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<p><input type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com'" value="Google" /></p>
```

http://jsbin.com/laray/1